# In which case Triggers not firing when records updated by Automated Process user

Tags: trigger, automated-process

I'm trying to figure out why some fields not populated on a custom object when the status is updated. Before Update trigger logic is straightforward, when status is changed, populate a field. And it is working when record updated manually. But it doesn't work when record updated by Automated Process. The problem is that I don't know how it updates record, I only see in Activity History that it was updated by Automated Process. Maybe there are some cases when it ignores triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a limitation to fire triggers, process builders, flows, and workflows on any database inserts or updates performed by the Automated Process user.Also,we have an existing [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LsMfQAK) which has been created for the same behavior.

Comment: this is only partially true; Automated Process user applies to Platform Events and all triggers ensuing from subscribing to the Platform Event _will_ execute

Comment: @cropredy what do you mean exacrly ?

Comment: @Ben2pop - what I meant is that Platform Events with trigger subscribers will run, by default, as `Automated Process` user and those triggers will execute; there are other actions performed on the database by `Automated Process` user that don't fire triggers (an example of which is in the Idea mentioned by Shirisha).

Comment: Is there a work around ?